# Check if the order item related product still exists in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I am using the following code to display quantities and product names for a series of WooCommerce orders:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

    // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
    $product = $item_data->get_product();

    $product_name = $product->get_name(); // Get the product name
    $item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity
    echo $item_data->get_quantity() . ' x ' . $product->get_name() . ' (' . $product->get_sku() . ')<br />' ;
}
```

All works well, but it gets stuck on a particular order where a product has been deleted (so the product id does not exist anymore).

Any way of checking for such a situation and displaying something like "product no longer exists" and moving on to the next product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will check if the product still exist to get its SKU *(handle also product variations)*:

```
// Loop through order items
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product_id   = (int) $item->get_product_id(); // The product ID
    $variation_id = (int) $item->get_variation_id(); // The variation ID
    $item_name    = $item->get_name(); // Get the product name
    $item_qty     = $item->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity

    // Get the product SKU: Check that the product exist
    if ( ( get_post_type( $product_id ) === 'product' && $variation_id === 0 )
    || ( get_post_type( $product_id ) === 'product' && $variation_id > 0 
    && get_post_type( $variation_id ) === 'product_variation' ) ) {
        // Get the WC_Product Object instance
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Check if it is a valid WC_Product Object instance (and that the sku exist)
        if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && $product->get_sku() != '' ) {
            $sku = ' ('.$product->get_sku().')'; // Get the sku
        } else {
            $sku = ''; // empty
        }
    } else {
        $sku = ''; // empty
    }

    // Output   
    echo $item_qty . ' &times; ' . $item_name . $sku . '<br>';
}
```

Tested and works.

**Note:** With Order items you can get the related product name from the order item instead *(as it's saved on the order item itself)*.